# Logging across sub-modules – how to access parent logger name from sub-modules?

Tags: python, logging, module

I am trying to add logging to my python application that has several modules and submodules. Several sites say to create child loggers in modules. The advantage I see is that the child logger inheriting the parent logging config, it will provide consistency for the logging output (handlers, formatters, ...).

So far I am defining the `__main__` class logger name in each class and concatenate it with the current class’ name (`parentName.childName`) to get the module’s class loggers. It does not feel right, nor scalable. How could I improve this so I don’t have to hard code the `__main__` class logger name in each class? Here is what my code looks like:

Py file that I run:

```
###app.py
import logging
from SubModule1 import *

class myApplication():
    loggerName='myAPI'
    def __init__(self, config_item_1=None,config_item_2=None,...config_item_N=None):
        self.logger=self.logConfig()
        self.logger.info("Starting my Application")
        self.object1=mySubClass1(arg1, arg2, ... argM)


    def logConfig(self):
        fileLogFormat='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        consoleLogFormat='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

        # create logger
        #logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.loggerName)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        ####CONSOLE HANDLER####
        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # create formatter
        consoleFormatter = logging.Formatter(consoleLogFormat)

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(consoleFormatter)

        # add ch to logger
        logger.addHandler(ch)

        ####FILE HANDLER####
        # create file handler and set level to debug
        fh = logging.FileHandler('API_Log.txt')
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create formatter
        fileFormatter = logging.Formatter(fileLogFormat)

        # add formatter to ch
        fh.setFormatter(fileFormatter)

        # add ch to logger
        logger.addHandler(fh)

        logger.info('Logging is started!!')

        return logger

    def connect(self):
        self.logger.info("Connecting to API")
        self.object1.connect()



if __name__=="__main__":
    config={"config_item_1": x,
            "config_item_2": y,
            ...
            "config_item_N": z
            }


    myApp=myApplication(config['config_item_1'],config['config_item_2'],...config['config_item_N'])
    myApp.connect()
```

Module:

```
###SubModule1.py
import logging
import app

class mySubClass1():
    appRootLoggerName='myAPI'
    def __init__(self,item1):
        self.logger=logging.getLogger(self.appRootLoggerName + '.'+mySubClass1.__name__)
        self.logger.debug("mySubClass1 object created - mySubClass1")   
        self.classObject1=item1
```

The line below is the one that is bothering me. What alternative to `self.appRootLoggerName + '.'+mySubClass1.__name__)` would keep the same logging configuration shared across my application’s modules/classes?

```
logging.getLogger(self.appRootLoggerName + '.'+mySubClass1.__name__)
```